# NetworkManager not creating in-memory connections

Tags: rhel, networkmanager

I'm comparing `Centos7` and `Rhel 7.2` installations.

rhel/centos installer creates simple network-scripts for existing adapters. They don't start automatically. `NetworkManager` sees them with names `enp0s*`.

On Centos it's enough to delete the network scripts created by the installer to make NM create and activate in-memory connections with dhcp:

```
rm -f /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp*
```

After reboot the connections appear in `nmtui` as `Wired connection n` and activate.

But on Rhel I don't see them in nmtui after deleting the scripts. The list is empty.

Why do I need this? Because it's a virtual machine and adapter names may change when I move it to another host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When NetworkManager starts and finds no connection for a device it might create an in-memory connection as you saw. The "no-auto-default" configuration disables that behavior. See 'man NetworkManager.conf'. Probably you have that configuration in place. Note there is also a package NetworkManager-config-server which provides such a configuration. Maybe you have it installed?

Note that NM creates these auto-default connections so that you can start it on a system without configuration and it would activate your network. Usually you don't use this on regular systems and instead you configure a persistent connection. If you modify the connection it becomes persistent and store to disk.

If you say that your device names might change, in that case you should instead unset "connection.interface-name" so that this connection applies to any device. See 'man nm-settings'.

And if you were unhappy with the connection from the installer, you could just modify it instead of deleting it (nmcli connection modify $name connection.auto-connect yes).

Comment: removing NetworkManager-config-server helped